# store form values in database

Tags: php

I have a form in which i use two dimensional array for field names.The fields names are below

myform[message][]

myform[name][]

myform[add][]

it means there are three arrays.Every array has arrays inside it.when i var_dump my form after putting values and submitting it.I get the below structure of 2d array.

```
array
  ''message'' => 
    array
      0 => string 'adnan' (length=5)
      1 => string 'khan' (length=4)
      2 => string 'salman' (length=6)
  ''name'' => 
    array
      0 => string 'khan' (length=4)
      1 => string 'kamran' (length=6)
      2 => string 'khan' (length=4)
  ''add'' => 
    array
      0 => string 'asad' (length=4)
      1 => string 'khan' (length=4)
      2 => string 'abrar' (length=5)
```

As you can see the associative array.I want to store the values of message,name and add in a database table having three fields to store the values of message,name and add fields in a single query by using some loop like foreach.
when i use this code

```
foreach($_REQUEST['myform'] as $val)
 foreach($val as $v)

  {
    echo $v;
  }
```

I get all the values of the array.But i think i am unable to save it to database table

as all the values are in the variable $v.How to store message in a message field,name in name field and add in an add field in a table of a db.

please advice.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($_REQUEST['myform'] as $field=>$val)
 // $field is the key
 foreach($val as $v)

  {
    echo $field . ' ' . $v;
  }
```

That will give you the field name to work with. I assume you know how to insert entries into a database already.

Answer (score 0):

At first make sure that length of message, name & add arrays are equal, then you can use this code to access all of your values:

```
foreach($_REQUEST['myform'] as $val)
{
    for($i=0;$i<count($val['message']);$i++){
        echo $val['message'][$i].'<br/>';
        echo $val['name'][$i].'<br/>';
        echo $val['add'][$i].'<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response...but with this code it gives a warning : Undefined index: message